# HTML Variable in script tag - Flask

Tags: html, variables, flask, jinja2

I'm using Flask (so Jinja templates). I've got acces to a Mapping table via a `@context.processor`. From this mapping table I need to retrieve a JSON Schema, depending of the type of an object : `reg.JsonSchemaMappingTable.get(type)`

Problem is, I have to do this in HTML. And, type is an HTML variable, so when I do something like `console.log({{ reg.JsonSchemaMappingTable.get(type)|tojson }})` it returns indefined because he doesn't know the `type` variable.

Do you guys have an idea how to do this ?

Comment: Actually I think it's more a Jinja2/Flask probem, isn't it ?

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION :

So, I finally pluged my brain in and got over it.

```
obj_type = data_selected.node.original._type 
map = {{reg.JsonSchemaMappingTable|tojson}}
mpa[obj_type]
```

So I just had to fully load my map, from flask into js, and use it as a js object !

Thanks guys, and sorry for bothring you with such a stupid question !